# when do we say a grammar to be unambiguous with respect to parse tree and derivation tree?

Tags: formal-languages, automata

In normal terminology we say that both the parse and derivation trees are same in meaning so if a grammar derives one string with left derivation as well as right derivation then it is ambiguous , if both left and right derivation correspond to 2 different parse trees.

Now what if I have the left-most derivation tree to be similar to right-most derivation tree ,and they both correspond to 1 parse tree so can I conclude that the grammar is unambiguous ?

Answer (score 1):

**An unambiguous grammar has same leftmost and rightmost derivation**:

---

Ambiguous Grammars

---

Definitions:

---

- If a grammar has more than one leftmost derivation for a single
  sentential form, the grammar is $\color{Blue}{\text{ambiguous}.}$
- If a grammar has more than one rightmost derivation for a single
  sentential form, the grammar is $\color{Blue}{\text{ambiguous}.}$
- The leftmost and rightmost *derivations* for a sentential form $\color{Red}{\text{may
     differ,}}$ even in an $\color{Green}{\text{unambiguous}}$ grammar.

Ref@https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~cavazos/cisc471-672/lectures/Lecture-08.pdf

---

**Comment :** Here, last point says an unambiguous grammar has same (or may not be) leftmost and rightmost derivation.

On the other hand, if a grammar has **more than one parse tree** for any string in given language, then grammar said to be **ambiguous**.